# SQLAlchemy foreign_keys relationship error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to set a relationship on SQLAlchemy to delete a table in cascade when the parent table is deleted.
The problem is my database structure is a bit awkward and that sqlalchemy doesn't like it at all.

Here a little look at it:

```
class Project(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'project'
  prj_id = sqla.Column(sqla.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
  name = sqla.Column(sqla.String)

  # Tariff used by project
  t_id = sqla.Column(sqla.INTEGER, sqla.ForeignKey("tariff.t_id"))

  # Tariff created by project
  tariff = relationship("Tariff", cascade="all, delete-orphan", foreign_keys=[prj_id])

class Tariff(Base):
  __tablename__ = "tariff"
  t_id = sqla.Column(sqla.INTEGER, primary_key=True)

  name = sqla.Column(sqla.String)
  prj_id = sqla.Column(sqla.INTEGER, sqla.ForeignKey("project.prj_id"))
```

To explain it a bit my Project table use a tariff, on the other hand my Tariff table can be created inside a project. A project can create a tariff and use another one and a tariff can be created outside of any project.

The error from SQLAlchemy is:
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Project.tariff - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.
But I'm pretty sure prj_id is a foreign key of Tariff, right?

This structure might be a bit clumsy but can I make it work with sqlalchemy or do I have to change it a bit?

Comment: "But I'm pretty sure prj_id is a foreign key of Tariff, right?" is a no, since `Project.prj_id` is "just" the primary key. `Tariff.prj_id` on the other hand is a foreign key.

Comment: Ilja Everilä Yep you got it. Thanks!